# Can't require linguistics or another lib, from file

Tags: ruby, linux

```
require 'linguistics'

`require': cannot load such file -- linguistics (LoadError)
```

But when I try test code in IRB - all fine

Comment: Is your file running in the context of an application which has an `.rvmrc` or `Gemfile`? Those files control availability of gems.

Comment: ...my file have .rb format
I start him by rake command in terminal for testing. And then
`require': cannot load such file -- linguistics (LoadError)

Comment: Are you trying to use this in a rails application? What do you mean you start your file with `rake` command?

Comment: Without Rails. In terminal I went to folder and write Rake command. Result: `require': cannot load such file -- linguistics (LoadError)

Comment: There is obviously a larger application you are modifying. Is there a `.rvmrc` or `Gemfile` in the root folder, where you run `rake`? Can you paste relevant section of the `Rakefile` - which will shows how your command is being processed to run your file (it might for example include `bundle exec` or similar references to `Bundler` which means it is looking in the Gemfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to edit your application's Gemfile

See this: http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html

In short, edit Gemfile and add a line

```
gem 'linguistics'
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

from your terminal.

Then try your rake command again

Comment: This file is located here?
ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem